# PHPMailer using SMTP TLS 1.1/1.2 on PHP 5.5.9 (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: php, phpmailer, tls1.2, php-5.5, smtp-auth

My SMTP provider recently dropped support for TLS 1.0 and my PHPMailer based email system running on PHP 5.5.9 would no longer connect to the server.

```
2018-08-14 16:28:19     SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 xxxx.xxxxxxxx.com ESMTP ecelerity 4.2.39.65443 r(Core:4.2.39.51) Tue, 14 Aug 2018 16:28:19 +0000
2018-08-14 16:28:19     CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO xxxxx.xxxxxxx.edu
2018-08-14 16:28:19     SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-xxxxxxx says EHLO to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49826
                                          250-8BITMIME
                                          250-PIPELINING
                                          250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
                                          250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
                                          250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                          250 STARTTLS
2018-08-14 16:28:19     CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-08-14 16:28:19     SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 continue
2018-08-14 16:28:19     SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2018-08-14 16:28:19     SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
2018-08-14 16:28:19     SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I spent quite a lot of time going through the steps at:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I finally gave up and upgraded to PHP 5.6 and the problem was resolved.  Is it possible to make TLS 1.2 work on PHP 5.5.9 or is this just not supported?

OpenSSL was 1.0.1f

Comment: Openssl 1.0.1f supports TLS 1.2 so I doubt it's that. More likely you have old CA certificates bundled with your PHP distro. It might help to do the openssl tests in the troubleshooting guide to see what it's expecting.

Comment: Well, I had tried downloading the cert file from curl and got rid of the error in the OpenSSL test line in the troubleshooting guide.  But that line has the path to cacert.pem embedded.  There’s no cafile or capath PHP directives in 5.5.9 so I couldn’t figure out how to direct PHP to use the newly downloaded certs.   I put them in the certs folder (default Ubuntu location) but that didn’t seem to help.

Comment: But my understanding was that 5.5.9 doesn’t do peer cert verification by default anyway?

Comment: Yes, that’s true. SSL in PHP isn’t terribly forthcoming about its errors. You can pass CA certs via the SMTPOptions property prior to 5.6.

Comment: Investigating this more--I think my problem may actually be this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65329

Comment: Well all that report says is that 1.2 works prior to PHP 5.6 because responsibility is passed to the underlying openssl lib, so I don’t think this helps you. You can use those `ssl://` and `tls://` prefixes in the `Host` property in PHPMailer, but they map to `SMTPSecure` values internally.